# Is it ok to have an `<a>` inside another `<a>`?

Tags: html

If I had a link to another page, and another link was put inside it, would that be ok to do? Is it allowed in HTML5 and if so, which browsers support it?

Trying this in Chrome 14.0.835.202, I see the text on the left gets linked, followed by the `#1` link, but the rest doesn't get linked.

Example:

```
<p>
 <a href="download?file=2">Example file.txt</a>
 [
  <a href="revision?file=2&id=8">This is an example revision that fixes bug 
   <a href="bug?file=2&id=1">#1</a>. 
   Version number updated.
  </a>
 ]
</p>
```

Comment: Note: it appears stackoverflow is incorrectly parsing your code snippet.

Comment: @calvinf There's nothing wrong with it on my end.

Comment: it looks like somebody else updated it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [HTML specification for links](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element): No.

> **Content model:**
> [Transparent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content) descendant.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [W3C specification for links HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2): No.

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

Or, in [the HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#links):

> Links are a conceptual construct, created by a, area, form, and link elements, that represent a connection between two resources

Comment: Yes, I was asking about HTML5. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @calvinf, sorry to steal your thunder. I thought it would be amusing to post an HTML5 parody of your answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot nest `a` elements in HTML 4 or 5. The key part of the spec that clarifies this is that when an `a` is a link, it is *interactive content*, and the content model of the `a` is

> [Transparent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content) descendent

[Reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Answer (score 5):

Even on HTML5 it's not allowed...

See here: [the Living HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

> The a element can be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

Answer (score -1):

It's not allowed, but you can do something like this:

```
<a href="revision?file=2&id=8">This is an example revision that fixes bug </a>
<a href="bug?file=2&id=1">#1</a>. 
<a href="revision?file=2&id=8">
  Version number updated.
</a>
```