# Link within a list-group-item class (itself a link) in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

(How) Can I place a link within a twitter bootstrap "list-group-item" that is itself a link without messing up the list-group-item format? (see below)

```
<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active">

    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">...</p>

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http" target="_blank">
    Share on Facebook
    </a>

</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `<a>` tags inside other `<a>` tags, that's invalid HTML. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863554/is-it-ok-to-have-an-a-inside-another-a) question.

You can make it clickable with jQuery though, with an hack like this:

`HTML` - use a div instead with a custom class and some data-tags:

```html
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item active list-group-item-linkable"
        data-link="http://www.google.com">

        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>

        <p class="list-group-item-text">...</p>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http"
            target="_blank">

            Share on Facebook
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS` - make it seem like a link:

```css
.list-group-item-linkable:hover {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

`JS` - the fun part:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-group-item-linkable').on('click', function() {
        // same window/tab:
        window.location.href = $(this).data('link');

        // new window/tab:
        //window.open($(this).data('link'));
    });

    $('.list-group-item-linkable a, .list-group-item-linkable button')
    .on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

I've also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdcmoreira/6ek29gr6/6/).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, you want the entire thing to be a link? It may take a couple more steps - nothing a little copy-and-pasting cant handle - but why not just manually provide an 'a' tag to each of the children of the "list-group"