# ui-sref - new tab without <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can open a link in a new tab with ui-sref in an **a** tag :

```
<a ui-sref="my-state"></a>
```

Now, I want to be able to open a link in a new tab, inside an **a** tag :

```
<a ui-sref="my-first-state">
    <a ui-sref="my-second-state" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"></a>
</a>
```

The problem is that we can't have an **a** tag inside another one ([Is it ok to have an `<a>` inside another `<a>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863554/is-it-ok-to-have-an-a-inside-another-a)).

How can I achieve this (knowing that opening a new tab with ui-sref is not possible with another tag than **a**) ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to put a link inside a link?

Comment: Each link is an order (basic ng-repeat on the first **a** tag), clicking on an order redirect to the order details. I can have a button inside the order (the first **a** tag) that redirects to a tracking page. I want that both can be opened in a new tab

Comment: Personally that looks like bad UX. I'd have a specific area which is clickable to the user and then another area outside the link which is the link to the tracking page.

Comment: I will share you a picture tomorrow (i'm in France and it is almost 1 am), it will be more understandful

Comment: Click [here](http://imgur.com/I3f9nAX) to see the dashboard.
You can either click on the order or click on the button "Suivre le livreur"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `button` and `ngClick` directive to provide clear and valid html and js code

To have opportunity of opening in new tab pass event in functions and then check for ctrl modifier

```
  e.preventDefault(); 
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){//ctrlKey - Windows, metaKey - OSX
    window.open('http://someurl.com','_blank')
  }
```

Comment: It will work perfectly but the expected behavior is to open the link in a new tab only when the user press CMD or CTRL (depending to OS) button during the click

Comment: That's why u have if condition inside function; 
CMD check -> event.metaKey === true; 
Ctrl check -> event.ctrlKey === true;

Comment: Sorry, i haven't seen the condition, I will try this tomorrow. Why is ng-click on a button better than ui-sref on an a ?

Comment: @Ziad cause nested `a` tags is not valid and also `ngClick` u can debbug and customize

Comment: Ok, i hadn't understood you were speaking about nested a tags. Thanks !